# How to run ROS not on Ubuntu?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to run (note: run, not install) ROS on a Linux distribution different from Ubuntu. Is that possible?

I read I can run ROS inside a container, using LXD or docker, but I don't know if it is the correct way to do that.
Is there a standard "solution" to this kind of problem, or am I obliged to install Ubuntu?

Edit: *I am excluding the creation of a full virtual machine or the installation directly on my main OS*.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385802/how-to-run-ros-not-on-ubuntu?/) by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-09-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mintybim](https://answers.ros.org/users/78444/mintybim/) on 2021-09-12**:
Hint: Don’t run ROS in docker on Windows, as the —net=host does not work there and you won’t be able to pass messages between your containerised nodes and any other node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two routes:

1. Official docker images: https://hub.docker.com/_/ros
2. You can always build from source. In fact, there's already a [tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Fedora-Development-Setup.html) that would need to be slightly modified depending on the distribution you're talking about.

---

Originally posted by [Jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/74436/jaron/) with karma: 56 on 2021-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Koen](https://answers.ros.org/users/83789/koen/) on 2021-09-06**:
If you build ROS2 from source, how do you add other packages? Can you apt-install those or do they need to be built from source as well? Do you add them to your personal workspace or the place where you build ros?

**Comment by [ROS_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/83560/ros_user/) on 2021-09-07**:
A question regarding route 1 (never used docker before).

Given that ROS docker image, can I run inside it multiple nodes and some graphical tools (like rviz) in a way that they are accessible/visible from my main OS? Could there be incompatibility problems?

**Comment by [Jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/74436/jaron/) on 2021-09-07**:
@Koen, if you have apt, the you can probably just follow the Ubuntu instructions anyways to install the binaries. But yes, generally, if you have apt, you can install all the apt binaries.

**Comment by [Jaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/74436/jaron/) on 2021-09-07**:
@ROS_user this really depends on what the host OS is but generally you need an X11 client on the host and forward GUIs through it. If you Google `GUI in docker` I'm sure you'll find stuff as this is not a ROS specific setup.